# how to stop for loop on another tty

Tags: linux, unix, command, kill

We are connecting to the same host via the same user. So, only our sessions/tty are different. If one of us starts a for loop such as:`for i in *; do command $i; done`, I don't know how to stop it. All I can do is search for the *command* name in `ps aux` and kill that instance of the command. But the for loop keeps going on, thus generating another *command* process.

How can I find that for loop and kill it?

Thank you,
Sam

Comment: Killing the [parent](https://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line) of `command` doesn’t work?

Comment: unfortunately, i can't find parent command. `pstree` doesn't work on the unix system i am using

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `pstree` to find shell where `for` executed.

For example, I run loop with command `for i in {1..1000}; do sleep 5; done`, then I do `pstree -p | grep sleep`, see output `|  -sshd(29695)---sshd(29707)---bash(29709)---sudo(29735)---bash(29736)---sleep(3843)`. Then `kill -9 29736` kill shell, where loop executed and stop it.

Comment: i am using tru64 system, and `pstree` isn't available here. Is there any other way to find parent process or the shell where `for` executed?

Comment: @SamGold, ouch. It that case you could use command `ps -o ppid= -p <PID>`. Where <PID> - PID of process running in loop.